# cannot seem to open audio stream from kinect

Tags: c#, xna, kinect

I'm having have problems accessing the kinect's audio stream for for use with speech control in my project. So far I have had no response from the audio stream. I am using xna with the latest kinect sdk pack installed.

The code I'm using is from a sample from the sdk using speech control in xna, but in a console application.

None of the listener events are being triggered which I think is down to the audio stream not starting for some reasons?

Any help would be appreciated.

This code is in the `InitializeKinect()` section of my program:

```
 // Obtain the KinectAudioSource to do audio capture
        KinectAudioSource source = kinectSensor.AudioSource;
        source.EchoCancellationMode = EchoCancellationMode.None; // No AEC for this sample
        source.AutomaticGainControlEnabled = false; // Important to turn this off for speech recognition
        source.Start();
        RecognizerInfo ri = GetKinectRecognizer();

        if (ri == null)
        {
            lol = "Could not find Kinect speech recognizer. Please refer to the sample requirements";
        }

        lol = "Using: {0}"+ ri.Name;

        // NOTE: Need to wait 4 seconds for device to be ready right after initialization

        using (var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id))
        {
            var colors = new Choices();
            colors.Add("Kinect");
            colors.Add("test center ");
            colors.Add("left");
            colors.Add("right");
            colors.Add("indirect controls");
            colors.Add("gesture control");
            colors.Add("exit application");

            var gb = new GrammarBuilder { Culture = ri.Culture };

            // Specify the culture to match the recognizer in case we are running in a different culture.                                 
            gb.Append(colors);

            // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
            var g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);
            sre.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechHypothesized);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
            sre.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected);

            using (Stream s = source.Start())
            {

                sre.SetInputToAudioStream(
                    s, new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(EncodingFormat.Pcm, 16000, 16, 1, 32000, 2, null));
                sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your Kinect plugged into the mains? USB can only power part of the Kinect and I noticed audio capabilities weren't working when it was only powered by USB.

Comment: yeah external power supply is connected and running the sample code in console works fine, im abit stumped on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be your problem.

```
using (var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id))
{
}
```

When the end of the `using` block is reached, the `sre` is closed. The recognition is async so the `using` block will close almost instantaneously. Instead, try doing this and see if it works.

```
var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri.Id)
//...
```

and then call `sre.Dispose()` at a more suitable time.

Comment: still the same issue, dont understand why its not starting the audio stream

Comment: @TobyLaroneBarrett - Sorry, I was looking at the async recognize call but the same concept may be applying to your SRE. There is nothing blocking the SRE `using` block (except the `LoadGrammar` call). Try removing the using block for the SRE and see if that fixes it.

Comment: same thing again, i understand where you are coming from on the using sections ending when they close

Comment: @TobyLaroneBarrett - Oh interesting. Reason I bring it up was because I answered an issue last week that had a similar problem with the SRE which was solved by not calling the using block (although they weren't using a `KinectAudioSource` IIRC). I'm not familiar with `KinectAudioSource` so not sure why that's not starting I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else can help :)

Comment: when i disable the depthframe event handle and enable code, the speech recognition works fine

Comment: You can post it as the answer if that was the issue (although I guess that leads to another issue of why that's required).

Comment: sadly the whole project needs the depth sensor enabled :(

Comment: @TobyLaroneBarrett - Thanks for accepting the answer but if your method worked better you can post that as an answer and accept it in a couple of days if you prefer :)